# Issue in Fama-French 3 factors Model

Tags: regression, fama-french, expected-return

I hope you are doing well.
As part of my thesis, I built 12 portfolios of 200 randomly selected stocks. I now want to calculate the Bs of the 3 Fama French factors for each stock, so that I can average them for a time T and calculate the expected return on my portfolio at time T. I have therefore constructed the HML and SMB portfolios on the basis of the stocks in my 12 portfolios. The problem is that when I run my regression to calculate the Beta of the factors (B1, B2, B3) for a stock, the p-values of the various factors (in particular SMB and HML) are above 0.05. Could you explain this? Do you have a possible explanation?
I'm doing this exercise on the period from 2018 to 2023.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Regards.

Comment: You need to give more details. What are the 12 portfolios that you are building? Are they size and book to market portfolios? Why are you building the factors from the 200 stocks and not using FF93 factors?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's 12 portfolios based on Equity size (from T1 to T6) and quality (T1Q0, T1Q1... T6Q0, T6Q1). I built SMB and HML portfolios based on the stock in my 12 portfolios, my risk-free rate is the AAA-Euro rated bonds and my Rm is MSCI World. (I also tried with the original FF portfolio SMB & HML, risk-free rate and Rm and it's not working). To be more precise, my thesis is about size premium. Therefore, the goal is to calculate the difference between observed return and expected return (calculated from Fama-French three factors model) for each portfolio (T1Q0... 6Q1).

Comment: To be more precise about my 12 portfolios, the Stocks inside are from different countries and different industries. My first analysis is to take all stocks existing in the market and build 12 portfolios according to size and quality. Therefore I have for example a panel T1Q0 of 10 000 stocks, and panel T1Q1 of 12 000 stocks. I selected randomly 200 stocks for each panel with one rule, all portfolio builds should have approximately the same Sharp Ratio.

Comment: For those voting to close as opinion based: The question lacks some detail and a definite answer might not exist, but it seems to me the question is concrete enough so that an answer based on sound theoretical arguments is possible.

Comment: To give an example and allow a possible response. The Fama-French 3 Factors works on Microsoft but not on Apple (P-value of SMB above 0.05). I don't know if it's possible to correct this or give a relevant explanation which allows me to keep the Fama-French model to calculate the expected return of Apple.